# simple calculator form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, calculator, form-for

I want to create a simple calculator form in Rails 3.1 just for understanding.  Via a form I want to get a number and multiplied it by two (for example).

I've created controller with index page (/index), then form in views:

```
<%= form_for @result do |f|%>
<%= f.label :number, 'Number' %>:
<%= f.text_field :number %>
<%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<%end%>
<%=@result%>
```

What I need to do with controller?

```
  def index
    @result = ''
  end
  def calculate
    @result = @number.to_i*2
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not gonna work. `form_for` is used to build forms for models that extend ActiveRecord. Use `form_tag('/calculate')` instead.

You need to define `match 'calculate' => 'your_controller_name#calculate' in config/routes.rb.

Additionally, you need a view for your calculate action - `calculate.html.erb` (you can call it differently but you'll have to specify `render 'view_name'`.

Alternatively, if you want to use the same view file, use `render :action => :index`

Forgot to mention.
To access the data from the form, you use `params[:key]` hash.
So in your case it would look like `@result = params[:number] * 2`

[This](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) book is a great place to start with Rails.

Also, [these](http://railscasts.com) screencasts are pretty helpful too

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is going to look for rails calculator examples... I made one after some time myself now, putting little pieces together from everywhere. Result is a currency calculator app, that fetches fresh exchange rate data from the web and lets you convert euros to a currency you want.

Link to github for anyone who maybe is a  total newcomer too and would like to know how to implement a calculator in rails: https://github.com/Veske/form
Also a link to heroku: http://harjutus.herokuapp.com